# Sampling points from multiple Gaussians

Tags: python, numpy

If I have one Gaussian with center=[x, y] and std=z I can sample one point using:

```
np.random.normal(loc=[x, y], scale=std)
```

But if I'm given two Gaussians with centers=[[x1, y1], [x2, y2]] and stds=[z1, z2] how can I sample points from these Gaussians together (or for n Gaussians)

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop,

```
import numpy as np

x1 = 0.; y1=0.; z1 = 1.
x2 = 1.; y2=0.; z2 = 1.
centers=[[x1, y1], [x2, y2]] 
stds=[z1, z2]

np.random.seed(1)
smpl = []
for c, std in zip(centers, stds):
    smpl.append(np.random.normal(loc=c, scale=std))
print(smpl)
```

but passing as lists also seems to work and would probably be more efficient,

```
np.random.seed(1)
smpl = np.random.normal(loc=centers, scale=std)
print(smpl)
```